# Select Form Element Not Saving from Plugin Options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms, select

I am certain it is something silly.  But I can't find it and with such simple code at a loss for anything else.  Having looked at many other plugins doing settings in a lot of ways can't really see how it is different from those doing similar code.  This is actually the select code from [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected).  After my code didn't work I went and checked the codex and tried it.  The really odd thing is that occasionally WordPress saves the selection.  But mostly it doesn't.

I can bypass the WordPress methods and use straight PHP, but then I learn nothing.  Many plugins are bypassing the register_settings method to deal with POST and DB.

Again as last time setup as a plugin.  As always your help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: myplug
    Version: 0.1
    Plugin URI: http://myplug.org
    Author: ME
    Description: Stupid plugin
     */

    add_action('admin_init', 'myplug_register_options');  // register options for the form
    add_action('admin_menu', 'myplug_admin_links');  // register admin menu hyperlinks

    /** Function to register form fields **/
    function myplug_register_options(){
            register_setting('myplug_options_group', 'myplug_settings', 'myplug_validate');
    }

    /** Function to add hyperlinks to the admin menus using hooks and filters. **/
    function myplug_admin_links() {
      add_options_page('myplug Setup', 'myplug', 'manage_options', 'myplug', 'myplug_admin_page' );  // add link to settings page
      add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'myplug_settings_link', 10, 2 );  // add link to plugin page
    }

    /** Function to create link for plugin_action_links filter **/
    function myplug_settings_link($links, $file){
            if ( $file == plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__). '/myplug.php')){
                    $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=myplug">' .__('Settings') . '</a>';
                    array_unshift( $links, $settings_link ); // place before other links
            }
    return $links;
    }

    /** Validate User Input **/
    function myplug_validate($input) {
            $input['select_it'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($input['select_it']);
    return($input);
    }

    /** Draw the Settings Page **/
    function myplug_admin_page(){
    ?>
    <div>
      <h2>Options</h2>
      <form method="post" action="options.php">
      <?php settings_fields('myplug_options_group'); ?>
      <?php $myplug_options = get_option('myplug_settings'); ?>
        <select name="input[select_it]">
            <option value="1" <?php selected( $input['select_it'], 1 ); ?>>1</option>
            <option value="2" <?php selected( $input['select_it'], 2 ); ?>>2</option>
            <option value="3" <?php selected( $input['select_it'], 3 ); ?>>3</option>
        </select>
      <?php submit_button(); ?>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `myplug_admin_page` function.

And see the `selected` calls inside it. `selected` works in a way that check the value of the item with the *current saved value*.

In your `selected` calls the *current saved value* should be `$input['select_it']` but.. **no** `$input` variable it's defined in that function.

In that function the current saved value is in the var `$myplug_options` (because of the `$myplug_options = get_option('myplug_settings')`).

So in `selected` calls replace `$input` with `$myplug_options` and I bet it will works.

Comment: LOL...ROFLMAO!!! Hysterical!  OMG!  I can't believe I didn't catch another stupid typo.  In this code that was completely by mistake and my eyes were tired.  I checked the production code and lo and behold I had used the wrong name!  I was using $var_settings instead of $var_options and for some reason my mind never caught it!  Thank you very much Guiseppe!

It's too bad I can't have you working next to me.  I would be much more productive with your eyes catching these silly mistakes!

Comment: LOL I was just thinking I knew it was something silly but I wasted a whole day looking for it!  So all that drama on the last comment at the start is kinda overkill! :-D  But too many posts/comments don't elate feelings so I will show mine! Thanks again Guiseppe!

Comment: You are welcome, @MarkFinch ;)